# vscode cannot type the letter i and the following letter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot type an `i` and the following letter in vscode. For `entity` I get `enty`, `active` I got `acte`. Somebody help me, please.
I tried to check the setting and I didn't find any problems.

Comment: You are probably triggering `Insert` mode.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling VS Code